# Перенос отображения логина на сайте CSS

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с вопросом о том, как грамотно организовать перенос имени пользователя при недостаточно широком боковом меню.

Смог добиться того, что если логин вмещается в следующей строке целиком, то не разрывается с первой при помощи такого кода:

```
span.name {
    color: yellow;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Но выглядит это все равно плохо из-за перенесенного восклицательного знака.

Уже пришел к тому, что, наверное, это невозможно реализовать при таком размере меню, потому что если имя пользователя достаточно большое, то оно в любом случае не влезет, и придется что-то переносить.

Как бы вы посоветовали организовать вывод имени пользователя?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вопросе четко не сформировано, чего вам надо. Что б восклицательный знак не переносился? Добавляйте его через :after а там можно через `position:absolute` поставить где вам надо.  Если ник нейм будет длинным это всё равно всё испортит.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 хочется узнать как в целом это обычно организовывают, не я же первый придумал выводить имя пользователя. И понятно, что проблемы будут, хочется знать какой из вариантов самый лучший, чтобы влияние проблем снизить к минимуму

Comment: Можешь запретить перенос и добавлять три точки, можешь сделать как ты делал, можешь увеличить место под логин, можешь на программном уровне запретить что б логин был больше N символов при регистрации... Это не проблема разработчика, это проблема дизайна, кто придумал тому и задавай этот вопрос.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 спасибо!